# Suppose F is a subset of the first category in metric space X, and E is a subset of F. Prove that E is of the first category in X.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I know that a subset of a nowhere dense subset is still nowhere dense. But since being of the first category doesn't imply nowhere dense, I couldn't use that fact directly. How should I proceed here?

Comment: Do you know the definition of  a first category set?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, namely being a countable union of nowhere dense subsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F=\cup _n F_n$ where each $F_n$ is nowhere dense. Now $E=\cup_n (E \cap F_n)$ and $E \cap F_n$ is a subset of a nowhere dense set , so it is nowhere dense.

Comment: Thanks so much. I can't believe I didn't see that.